Does the nucleophilicity of an alkene increase with increase in alpha hydrogen or hyperconjugative structures?
If the alpha - hydrogen of a Carbon - Carbon double bond increases, then its stability increases. So, its nucleophilicity should decrease. But at the same time, a +H and +I group like CH3 should also increase the magnitude of negative charge on C=C.
So does nucleophilicity increase for an alkene with increase in alpha hydrogen?
Apologies if this is a dupes, but I could not find an answer on Google search.

Hmm, I think sterics would be a bigger issue.

When the number of alpha carbons increases, the +I effect causes the electron density on the carbon of the C=C bonds to increase, making this double bond act like a nucleophile. Note that if the number of alpha hydrogens increases, for example, with more -CH3 groups, it causes steric hindrance and reduces their nucleophilicity.
